Is there a way to store switches in AS2?
So, im currently making a project, and in this project there is a code where i have a switch condition with various cases, but, is there any way to store that switch condition in a class file? Or a variable?
Here's an example of what im trying to say:
switch (X) {
    case 1 :
        doThing();
        break;
    case 2 :
        doThing();
        break;
    case 3 :
        doThing();
        break;
    }

Could be simplified by:
list.switch()

And then have the actual switch in a class, or stored in a variable?

I think AS2 treats all function arguments as optional, so you can NOT pass an argument and retrieve its value from a local variable. Something like that:
var switchCase;

function switcher(what): void
{
    if (what == undefined)
    {
        what = switchCase;
    }
    else
    {
        switchCase = what;
    }
    
    switch (what)
    {
        // Your switch clause.
    }
}

Usage:
// Set switch into position:
switcher(3);

// Repeat the actions for the current position:
switcher();

You can, of course, wrap it into a class as well.
